# Having a trouble getting List of Strings from array.xml file and parsing them to array of floats android

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

Getting the strings from the array file and parsing them into an array of Float numbers. Once I run the code I get a null pointer exception but an array is not empty. help...
The code inside OnCreate method:

```
    String[] lat = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.latitudes);

    List<Float> latitudes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String l : lat) {
            latitudes.add(Float.parseFloat(l));
        }
```

The code inside array.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<array name="latitudes">
    <item >51.885375</item><!-- CIT Main Campus -->
    <item >51.884774</item><!-- Library -->
    <item >51.884966</item><!-- Nexus Student Centre -->
    <item >51.885651</item><!-- Admin Office -->
    <item >51.883761</item><!-- Canteen -->
    <item >51.884694</item><!-- Stadium -->
    <item >51.884721</item><!-- Gym -->
    <item >51.884642</item><!-- Car Park -->
    <item >51.886531</item><!-- Melbourne Exam Hall -->
    <item >51.895137</item><!-- CIT Crawford College of Art and Design -->
    <item >51.896025</item><!-- CIT Cork School Of Music -->
</array>

<array name="longitudes">
    <item >-8.534452</item><!-- CIT Main Campus -->
    <item >-8.534278</item><!-- Library -->
    <item >-8.535195</item><!-- Nexus Student Centre -->
    <item >-8.533758</item><!-- Admin Office -->
    <item >-8.533522</item><!-- Canteen -->
    <item >-8.537159</item><!-- Stadium -->
    <item >-8.534777</item><!-- Gym -->
    <item >-8.538809</item><!-- Car Park -->
    <item >-8.533832</item><!-- Melbourne Exam Hall -->
    <item >-8.481826</item><!-- CIT Crawford College of Art and Design -->
    <item >-8.468063</item><!-- CIT Cork School Of Music -->
</array>

</resources>
```

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: It could be that the the `lat` array contains `null` values, in this case `l` could be `null`

Comment: @Arkadiy I have made an image of stacktrace.

Comment: @Titus But I am adding an array to it referring to the xml file and by the way it works if there is only a text in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **string-array** instead of **array**

Comment: Thanks very much that was the problem that was wrecking my head :)